# Is every stably free module of commutative group ring free?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, group-rings

Is every stably free module of commutative group ring free? if not can you give me an example of commutative group ring with nonfree stably free module.

Comment: Do you mean the integral group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$? And are you interested in arbitrary (infinitely generated) abelian groups? For a finitely generated abelian group $G$, every stably free module for $\mathbb{Z}G$ is free. (F.E.A. Johnson, "Stably free cancellation for abelian group rings", Arch. Math. 102, p. 7-10 (2014). https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-013-0599-8 )

Comment: Surely this is true for all torsion-free abelian groups, as they (and the corresponding group rings) are direct limits of finitely generated free ones (and their group rings), for which Quillen-Suslin applies? SF implies F is preserved by direct limits, so in general it would be enough to do it for finitely generated abelian groups anyway.